# What other special modules (files) exist at the package level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, naming-conventions

I know of only two filenames that will be interpreted meaningfully: `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`

`__init__.py`: The init file for a package. Executed when a package is first imported/imported from. If this file is present, then the directory is considered a package (there also exists "namespace packages" that don't have init modules)

`__main__.py`: The main entry point for a package. This file is executed when running the package from the commandline. (ex: `python -m PackageName`)

What other files can exist and what do they do?

Comment: I don't know if there are *currently* any others, but I would assume that anything that matches `__*__.py` is reserved for use by Python itself, and you shouldn't try to create a file of your own with such a name.

Comment: But, these dunder files *are* meant to be created. Part of the package..

Comment: Maybe there aren't currently any. I would accept definitive proof of that as the answer.

Comment: I mean, don't create a file with *another* similar name like `__mycustomdunder__.py`. `__main__.py` and `__init__.py` are meant to created, of course.

Comment: I would humbly disagree with that philosophy: I have several custom patterns/idioms implemented through custom dunders. It's the tits!

Comment: I would argue that the pythonic way is to, in fact, create more of these where appropriate. Messing with the internals is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: I wonder where, exactly, the logic that handles these file names is. Perhaps somewhere in the import mechanism...

Comment: dunders reserved by python. It's very likely that your code will break if they ever decide that your "custom dunder" is now going to be an official one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's definite proof of only `__main__` and `__init__` being the only special files, definitely haven't seen any documentation for it. But, there's a decent way of asserting that the probability of those being the only ones is high by searching for dunders in the [file finder for the `C`Python repo.](https://github.com/python/cpython/find/master)

Only `__init__.py`'s and `__main__.py`'s; @chepner's point is also highlighted by the sole other dunder: `__future__.py`, other usages of `__*__.py` should indeed not be used as it might conflicts with some future Python file.

Since I had the source around, grepping for `"__.*__.py"` in all files didn't yield any other result other than the aforementioned trio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135691/discussion-between-jim-fasarakis-hilliard-and-inversus).

Comment: Near as I can tell, `__future__.py` has no special meaning, though of course there is the "magic module" `__future__` you can import new language features from.